# Dump a single document in RxDb

Tags: javascript, json, couchdb, pouchdb

I have an instance of an RxDB document which I would like to serialize into JSON. But, I just want the raw data, not any of the instance methods, etc...

I see there is a dump() function for the entire database, but is there anything similar on the document level?

Anyways, this is what I'm seeing via document.get():

[image]

I just want the fields up until `peerID` and not all that internal stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is possible via the undocumented `myDocument.toJSON()` method.